# Picasso garbage collecting Target

Tags: android, kotlin, garbage-collection, picasso

I'm using Kotlin and Picasso to display images from URL. Now I am sharing some content with an Intent, and I am sharing the image and some text. Here is my code:

```
         Picasso.get().load(URL).into(object : Target {
            override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap?, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?) {

                val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
                    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getBitmapFromView(bitmap, this@DealActivity))
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textForShare)

                    type = "image/jpeg"
                }
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "SEND"))

            }
            override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) { }
            override fun onBitmapFailed(e: java.lang.Exception?, errorDrawable: Drawable?) { }
        })
```

This works, some of the time. Most of the time, nothing happens. Here is my log:

```
2020-05-14 22:12:52.378 11310-11402/il.co.nazooza D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R19]+2ms 
2020-05-14 22:12:52.380 11310-11430/il.co.nazooza D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R19]+3ms 
2020-05-14 22:12:53.150 11310-11430/il.co.nazooza D/Picasso: Hunter      decoded      [R19]+773ms 
2020-05-14 22:12:53.151 11310-11402/il.co.nazooza D/Picasso: Dispatcher  batched      [R19]+775ms for completion
2020-05-14 22:12:53.195 11310-11310/il.co.nazooza D/Picasso: Main        canceled     [R19]+813ms target got garbage collected
```

I have read that the target must be made into a field, but I'm struggling to to this with Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this code is in an `Activity`, so you just need to add a field to your `Activity` and store it there:

```kotlin
class MyActivity: Activity() {
    private var shareTarget: Target? = null
    //...
    fun someMethod() {
        shareTarget = object : Target {
            override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap?, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?) {

                val shareIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
                    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getBitmapFromView(bitmap, this@DealActivity))
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textForShare)

                    type = "image/jpeg"
                }
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "SEND"))
                // don't need to store it any longer
                shareTarget = null

            }
            override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) { }
            override fun onBitmapFailed(e: java.lang.Exception?, errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
                // don't need to store it any longer
                shareTarget = null
            }
        }
        Picasso.get().load(URL).into(shareTarget)
    }
    // ...
}
```

Note that this assumes you only have one of these requests in-flight at a time.  If you have multiple, you'll have to store them in a collection of some sort, or multiple variables, or something like that.